# Does the Windows 7 RC have any issues with the MacBook Pro on BootCamp?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, vmware-fusion, bootcamp

I am wanting to get my feet wet with the Windows 7 x64 RC before I need to start supporting it.  Has anyone run the RC on their MacBook Pro with bootcamp?

Also,   Have you pulled the bootcamp partition into VMware Fusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm writing this from a Macbook pro running windows 7 Beta x64 (will be upgrading to RC later today) and it runs fine. The only problems I've had is with some of the drivers, this is because i'm running a late 2007 MBP that officially doesn't support x64, but it works fine.

I had to get hold of the 64bit apple drivers, as there not on my Leopard CD, but once I had them it worked, aside from some issues with the F keys and the BootCamp icon that is usually in the task bar isn't there, however I suspect this is mostly to do with my MBP, if you have a later version that fully supports x64 it should be fine.

I've pulled my BootCamp partition into VMWare Fusions with no issues what so ever, but you do need to tell fusions its a server 2008 OS.

Answer (score 4):

http://ourcoffeestops.com/2009/01/guide-windows-7-x64-build-7000-on-a-macbook-pro/